# Nasm：correct use ROR

Tags: assembly, x86, nasm

I am in assembly language, when using ror, the teacher suggested that I have a mistake, but I don't understand why there will be a mistake.

```
%include"io.inc"
section .text
global CMAIN
CMAIN:
    GET_DEC 4, eax
    GET_DEC 4, ebx
    ror eax, ebx ; line 7
    PRINT_UDEC 4, eax
    NEWLINE
    xor eax, eax
    ret
```

```
program.asm:7: error: invalid combination of opcode and operands
```

Comment: The ROR instruction can't just use any register as a count. Only register _CL_ (the bottom 8 bits of _ECX_ can be used for such purpose. See: https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror . The value in _CL_ should be a value from 0-31 in 32-bit code.

Comment: Now is a good time to learn how to read error messages. "Invalid combination of opcode and operands." This strongly suggests that the problem is that you used an invalid combination opcode and operands. Check the opcode and operands and confirm that they are a valid combination. https://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/rcl:rcr:rol:ror shows the valid operands for the ror opcode.

Comment: As @RaymondChen says, NASM's error message is accurate and helpful.  This is usually the case with NASM, unlike some assemblers (especially GAS), NASM error messages generally point you in the right direction so it's a good choice for learning asm.

Comment: I forgot about this, thanks for the reminder.@MichaelPetch

Comment: Just had a look, it's pretty comprehensive here, thanks a lot.@RaymondChen